# searching in n 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Hi 
I need the following logic to implement on an n arrays(of 2-dimensional) .Here I have considered 3 arrays of one dimensional

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[4]={2,1,4,7},b[4]={3,-3,-8,0},c[4]={-1,-4,-7,6},sum,i,j,k,val=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            for(k=0;k<4;k++) {
                sum = a[i]+b[j]+c[k];
                if(sum == val)
                printf("%d  %d  %d\n", a[i], b[j], c[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

**Output:**
2  -8  6 **;**
1  3  -4 **;**
1  0  -1 **;**
4  3  -7 **;**
4  -3  -1 **;**
4  0  -4 **;**
7  -3  -4 **;**
7  0  -7 **;**

Comment: Could you make your question clearer? What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I have 6 tables and I am putting these into a 2-dimenssional array.I will provide a value say 10 like how val=0 here . I need to search from these tables all the combination values that make up 10.The value will be computed taking values from all these tables.I hope 'm clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [C syntax in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Multidimensional_arrays) for syntax information.

In practice, you need to use int array[3][4] = ... to create an array with 3 rows and 4 columns. Later in code replace the accesses to current a, b and c arrays with a fixed row index for each case.

Rest of the implementation is left as an exercise as this sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem :-)
I will not post my full solution because the problem appears to be homework. Just a few pointers ...

I solved it with recursion: the simplification process I used was **finding a sum of `target` in `n` arrays is the same as finding a sum of `target - ONE_ELEMENT` in `n-1` arrays.**

Example using your 3 arrays and a target of zero

```
find 3 elements with sum 0           in {2, 1, 4, 7}, {3, -3, -8, 0}, {-1, -4, -7, 6}
find 2 elements with sum 0 - 2 (-2)  in {3, -3, -8, 0}, {-1, -4, -7, 6}
find 1 elements with sum -2 - 3 (-5) in {-1, -4, -7, 6}              NOT FOUND
find 1 elements with sum -2 - -3 (1) in {-1, -4, -7, 6}              NOT FOUND
find 1 elements with sum -2 - -8 (6) in {-1, -4, -7, 6}              YAY! FOUND
...
```

---

To make it work easily, I had create a data structure for the arrays and to come up with a way to pass information between the several invocations of the recursive function (I used another array allocated in the helper recursive setup function).

The structure for the arrays was

```
struct sizedarray {
  int *data;
  size_t nelems;
};
```

and the prototypes for the recursive and helper functions was

```
findtarget(int target, struct sizedarray *arrays, size_t narrays);
findtarget_recursive(int target, struct sizedarray *arrays, size_t narrays, size_t level, int *saved);
```

---

Edited to add a working solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* struct to hold arrays with varying sizes */
struct sizedarray {
  int *data;
  size_t nelems;
};

void findtarget_recursive(int target,
                         struct sizedarray *arrays,
                         size_t narrays,
                         size_t level,
                         int *saved) {
  size_t k, j;
  struct sizedarray *curarray = arrays + level;

  /* if no arrays left to search return */
  if (level == narrays) {
    return;
  }
  /* if only 1 arrays do not recurse */
  if (level + 1 == narrays) {
    for (k = 0; k < curarray->nelems; k++) {
      if (curarray->data[k] == target) {
        /* print saved elements from previous arrays */
        for (j = 0; j < level; j++) {
          printf("%d ", saved[j]);
        }
        /* print current element from current array */
        printf("%d\n", curarray->data[k]);
      }
    }
    return;
  } else {
    /* when 2 or more arrays left, recurse */
    for (k = 0; k < curarray->nelems; k++) {
      saved[level] = curarray->data[k];
      findtarget_recursive(target - curarray->data[k],
                           arrays,
                           narrays,
                           level + 1,
                           saved);
    }
  }
}

int findtarget(int target, struct sizedarray *arrays, size_t narrays) {
  int *saved = NULL;
  saved = malloc(narrays * sizeof *saved);
  /* assume it worked, needs something when it fails */
  if (saved) {
    findtarget_recursive(target, arrays, narrays, 0, saved);
    free(saved);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  int a0[] = {2, 1, 4, 7};
  int a1[] = {3, -3, -8, 0};
  int a2[] = {-1, -4, -7, 6};
  int a3[] = {1, 5, 6, 7};
  int a4[] = {-10, -4, -1, 3, 8};
  int a5[] = {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
  struct sizedarray arrays[6];
  int target = 0;

  arrays[0].data = a0; arrays[0].nelems = sizeof a0/sizeof *a0;
  arrays[1].data = a1; arrays[1].nelems = sizeof a1/sizeof *a1;
  arrays[2].data = a2; arrays[2].nelems = sizeof a2/sizeof *a2;

  findtarget(target, arrays, 3);

  arrays[3].data = a3; arrays[3].nelems = sizeof a3/sizeof *a3;
  arrays[4].data = a4; arrays[4].nelems = sizeof a4/sizeof *a4;
  arrays[5].data = a5; arrays[5].nelems = sizeof a5/sizeof *a5;

  puts("\n\nwith 6 arrays ...");
  findtarget(target, arrays, 6);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I could not get what your tying to tell... If posssible can you post ur solution which will be of a gr8 help... :) n by de way dis nt homework 'm struggling tats it ...

Comment: @Sumanth: see my edit. Also you can [see the code "running" at codepad](http://codepad.org/KRTQBbD5).